# Почему Postgresql13 не присваивает пароль пользователю?

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql

Пытаюсь создать пользователей в БД: `worker1`, `worker2`, `worker3` с паролями.
Далее проверяю, могу ли подключиться без пароля `psql -U worker1 -w -d postgres` и она дает подключение... Почему?
Создавал пользователей так:

```
CREATE USER worker1 PASSWORD '123456';
ALTER USER worker1 WITH PASSWORD '123456';
```

1. Как правильно создать пользователей чтобы применялись пароли?
2. Как запретить Postgresql авторизацию без пароля?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

1. Находим `pg_hba.conf` как правило путь к нему `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf`
2. меяем все методы с `trust` на `md5` или `password` - (не желательно) или `scram-sha-256`
3. перезапускаем процесс `brew services restart postgres` так как устанавливал через HomeBrew

Теперь просит пароль на каждое подключение.